# How can I jump to a new line on a html page while working on a js file using the DOM?

Tags: dom, newline

I want to make a paragraph on a web page while working on a js file.

I tried this.

```
 document.getElementById("stat").textContent=`
    Title : Bullet Train <br>
    Duration: 190min <br>
    Director: David Leitch<br>
    Starring: Brad Pitt`
```

I got this.
"Title : Bullet Train
Duration: 190min
Director: David Leitch
 Starring: Brad Pitt"

Was expecting this.

```
    Title : Bullet Train
    Duration: 190min 
    Director: David Leitch
    Starring: Brad Pitt`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using textContent replace it with innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById("stat").innerHTML=`
Title : Bullet Train <br>
Duration: 190min <br>
Director: David Leitch<br>
Starring: Brad Pitt`
```